# Error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [35]’ and ‘const char [2]’ to binary ‘operator+’

Tags: c++, string, c-preprocessor, stdstring

At the top of my file I have

```
#define AGE "42"
```

Later in the file I use ID multiple times including some lines that look like

```
std::string name = "Obama";
std::string str = "Hello " + name + " you are " + AGE + " years old!";
str += "Do you feel " + AGE + " years old?";
```

I get the error:

> "error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [35]’ and ‘const char [2]’ to binary ‘operator+’"

on line 3. I did some research and found it was because of how C++ was treating the different strings and was able to fix it by changing "AGE" to "string(AGE)." However, I accidentally missed one of the instances until today and was wondering why the compiler wasn't complaining even though I still had an instance where it was just "AGE".

Through some trial and error I found that I only need `string(AGE)` on lines where I don't concatenate another string that was created in the function body.

My questions is "what is going on in the background that C++ doesn't like concatenating a string with a string put there by the preprocessor unless you are also concatenating string that you defined in the function."

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. Even though I decided to get rid of the macro I am glad I know the "why."

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Consider this:

```
std::string str = "Hello " + "world"; // bad!
```

Both the rhs and the lhs for `operator +` are `char*`s. There is no definition of `operator +` that takes two `char*`s (in fact, the language doesn't permit you to write one). As a result, on my compiler this produces a "cannot add two pointers" error (yours apparently phrases things in terms of arrays, but it's the same problem).

Now consider this:

```
std::string str = "Hello " + std::string("world"); // ok
```

There *is* a definition of `operator +` that takes a `const char*` as the lhs and a `std::string` as the rhs, so now everyone is happy.

You can extend this to as long a concatenation chain as you like. It can get messy, though. For example:

```
std::string str = "Hello " + "there " + std::string("world"); // no good!
```

This doesn't work because you are trying to `+` two `char*`s before the lhs has been converted to `std::string`. But this is fine:

```
std::string str = std::string("Hello ") + "there " + "world"; // ok
```

Because once you've converted to `std::string`, you can `+` as many additional `char*`s as you want.

If that's still confusing, it may help to add some brackets to highlight the associativity rules and then replace the variable names with their types:

```
((std::string("Hello ") + "there ") + "world");
((string + char*) + char*)
```

The first step is to call `string operator+(string, char*)`, which is defined in the standard library. Replacing those two operands with their result gives:

```
((string) + char*)
```

Which is exactly what we just did, and which is still legal. But try the same thing with:

```
((char* + char*) + string)
```

And you're stuck, because the first operation tries to add two `char*`s.

Moral of the story: If you want to be sure a concatenation chain will work, just make sure one of the first two arguments is explicitly of type `std::string`.

Comment: I had a similar code `throw out_of_range("ModuleName:: "  __FUNCTION__  ": Exception message");` and it compiled fine with VS2010. I am not sure why or how that happened. But when I tried to compile it with gcc I got error. I had to finally do something like `throw out_of_range(string("ModuleName:: ") + __FUNCTION__ + ": Exception message");`

Comment: @sabertooth1990 gcc isn't my compiler, but from a quick look at its documentation, it appears that the type of the  `__FUNCTION__` extension is `char[]`. You can concatenate string literals together by writing them all in a row, but that doesn't work with arrays or pointers. vcc must treat it as a literal.

Comment: It is also because the `operator+` is left-associative.  So as the following expression `"Do you feel " + "42" + " years old?"` becomes `("Do you feel " + "42") + " years old?"` and the compiler cannot find a method that can handle this.  Whereas when there's an `std::string` in any of the operands (LHS or RHS to the `+`) then the `operator+` has an overloaded method to handle the string literal.

Comment: I don't like to imply the left-hand string is any different from the other strings, so I start with an empty string and concatenate all you want after it. `std::string value = std::string() + "Happy Birthday! You are now " + AGE + " years old";`

Answer (score 19):

`AGE` is defined as `"42"` so the line:

```
str += "Do you feel " + AGE + " years old?";
```

is converted to:

```
str += "Do you feel " + "42" + " years old?";
```

Which isn't valid since `"Do you feel "` and `"42"` are both `const char[]`. To solve this, you can make one a `std::string`, or just remove the `+`:

```
// 1.
str += std::string("Do you feel ") + AGE + " years old?";

// 2.
str += "Do you feel " AGE " years old?";
```

Answer (score 5):

In line 2, there's a `std::string` involved (`name`). There are operations defined for `char[] + std::string`, `std::string + char[]`, etc. `"Hello " + name` gives a `std::string`, which is added to `" you are "`, giving another string, etc.

In line 3, you're saying

```
char[] + char[] + char[]
```

and you can't just add arrays to each other.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot concatenate raw strings like this. `operator+` only works with two `std::string` objects or with one `std::string` and one raw string (on either side of the operation).

```
std::string s("...");
s + s; // OK
s + "x"; // OK
"x" + s; // OK
"x" + "x" // error
```

The easiest solution is to turn your raw string into a `std::string` first:

```
"Do you feel " + std::string(AGE) + " years old?";
```

Of course, you should not use a macro in the first place. C++ is not C. Use `const` or, in C++11 with proper compiler support, `constexpr`.

Comment: Or you could just remove the `+`: `"Do you feel " AGE`

Comment: ... which confuses other programmers and opens the room for many maintenance nightmares. Just getting rid of the macro is the best solution.

Comment: not sure if calling them 'raw strings' is appropriate

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, an even simpler fix would be to just get rid of the "+" all together because AGE is a string literal and what comes before and after are also string literals.  You could write line 3 as:

`str += "Do you feel " AGE " years old?";`

This is because most C/C++ compilers will concatenate string literals automatically.  The above is equivalent to:

`str += "Do you feel " "42" " years old?";`

which the compiler will convert to:

`str += "Do you feel 42 years old?";`

Comment: all c/c++ compilers will concatenate adjacent string literals otherwise they aren't c/c++ compilers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my code. I was concatenating a string to create a string. Below is the part of code.

```
int scannerId = 1;
std:strring testValue;
strInXml = std::string(std::string("<inArgs>" \
                        "<scannerID>" + scannerId) + std::string("</scannerID>" \
                        "<cmdArgs>" \
                        "<arg-string>" + testValue) + "</arg-string>" \
                        "<arg-bool>FALSE</arg-bool>" \
                        "<arg-bool>FALSE</arg-bool>" \
                        "</cmdArgs>"\
                        "</inArgs>");
```