# Invalid operands of types ‘const char [8]’ and ‘const char*’ to binary ‘operator+

Tags: c++, fopen

I am trying to write a Fopen statement like this:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("client." + receiver->get_identifier().c_str() + ".vol", "a+");
```

where receiver->get_identifier() returns a string. However, I am getting the error in the title. I read the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936246/error-invalid-operands-of-types-const-char-35-and-const-char-2-to-binar) but wasn't having any luck because the first argument of fopen is const char*. What do I have to change to get this to compile?

Comment: Dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936246/error-invalid-operands-of-types-const-char-35-and-const-char-2-to-binar) but is really just a typo.  Get rid of the `.c_str` and wrap the whole thing in () and then use `.c_str()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
receiver->get_identifier().c_str()
```

returns a `const char*`, not a `std::string`, so [`operator+`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) cannot kick in (one argument of it must be a `std::string`). Removing the `c_str()` and converting at the end with `std::string::c_str()` should do the trick

```
fopen(("client." + receiver->get_identifier() + ".vol").c_str(), "a+");
```

This is because you'd have a `const char*` plus a `std::string`, and `operator+` will work.

If you may wonder why one cannot define an `operator+` for `const char*`s, that's because C++ does not allow operator overloading for fundamental types; at least one argument must be of a user-defined type.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the first argument to

```
(string("client.") + receiver->get_identifier() + ".vol").c_str()
```

This will add `std::string` objects with C-Style strings, [which can be done](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B), and only take the character pointer at the end (via `.c_str()`). Your code now tries to add C-Style strings, which is not possible.