# Overloading operator+ for const char*

Tags: c++, overloading

```
PString& PString::operator+(const PString &p) {
PString ps3;
ps3.rec = this->rec + p.rec;
return ps3;
}
```

This is how my function looks like and this is mine main()

```
PString ps1("Ovo je neki text");
PString ps2("ovo je neki drugi text");
PString ps3(ps1);
ps1 = ps2;
PString ps4;
ps4 = ps1 + ps2;
cout << ps4 << endl;
```

And this is error message i get

```
vezba.cpp:99:29: error: invalid operands of types ‘char*’ and ‘char* const’ to binary ‘operator+’
 ps3.rec = this->rec + p.rec;
                         ^
vezba.cpp:98:13: warning: reference to local variable ‘ps3’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
 PString ps3;
```

this is in my class:

```
class PString {
private:
char *rec;
```

ok so i changed operator+ to this

```
PString& PString::operator+(const PString &p) {
PString ps4;
std::string(ps4.rec) = std::string(this->rec) + std::string(p.rec);
return ps4;
}
```

and now i get warning

```
vezba.cpp: In member function ‘PString& PString::operator+(const PString&)’:
vezba.cpp:98:13: warning: reference to local variable ‘ps4’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
 PString ps4;
```

and nothing prints out

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i am new here, can you suggest me what to do to improve ?

Comment: PString is a typedef for char*?

Comment: Just wondering, what's the point of defining your own string implementation, why not just use `std::string`??

Comment: PString is only char*

Comment: this is for practice

Comment: ok, understand. `+` operator is not overloaded for concatenation for C-style strings (`char *`). It's overloaded for `str::string`. 
So one option you have is to manually allocate a buffer for the new string and use `strcat`.

Comment: i am not using string here

Comment: The short answer: char* is not a string. Learn the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google it: "operator+ const char"... [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936246/error-invalid-operands-of-types-const-char-35-and-const-char-2-to-binar)

quote dlf:

> Both the rhs and the lhs for `operator+` are `char*s`. There is no definition of `operator+` that takes two `char*`s (in fact, the language doesn't permit you to write one).

edit: you should probably use `std::string`...

edit2: sure? its trivial...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string ps1("Ovo je neki text");
    std::string ps2("ovo je neki drugi text");
    std::string ps3(ps1);
    ps1 = ps2;
    std::string ps4;
    ps4 = ps1 + ps2;
    std::cout << ps4 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[On codepad](http://codepad.org/O0lsI3jT)

Comment: i added an example... but its trivial

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to use `+` for string concatenation is to use the standard library `std::string`. If you are trying to implement that yourself, You will need to overload `+` for your PString class. built-in char*s do not allow you to concatenate them with `+`.

Comment: True. I did not see your answer before i posted this.

Comment: Oh man, your code is funny. You recreate the string class, by using string internally! Why not drop PString?