# append chars to string

Tags: c++, string, char

I have two chars and I want to create a string concatenating them:

```
char a = '1';
char b = '2';

string s = "(" + a + "," + b + ")";
```

What's the easiest way to achieve that?
Since the first element "(" is a string, by concatenating the elements from left to right it should work, since each char will be casted into a string and appended.

However the compiler doesn't seem to like it.

```
error: invalid operands of types 'const char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936246/error-invalid-operands-of-types-const-char-35-and-const-char-2-to-binar).  You get your specific error because in `"(" + a`, the `a` is converted to an `int` and the add gives a pointer.  Then you try to add `","` to it.

Comment: I like a stringstream for stuff like this: `std::ostringstream strm; strm << "(" << a << "," << b << ")";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"("` is not a `std::string`. It is a `char[2]` C string array. Make it `std::string` by using the [`s` literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s):

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
std::string s = "("s + a + ","s + b + ")"s;
```

This can still fail if you try to do something like this:

```
std::string s = a + b + "."s; // error
```

In this case you can simply start with an empty string:

```
std::string s = ""s + a + b + "."s;
```

Another option is to use [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to build the string:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "(" << a << "," << b << ")";
std::string s3 = oss.str();
```

Comment: Do built-in literals technically count as *user*-defined literals? As far as I know UDL suffixes must start with a `_`, for starter.

Comment: i did not know about the s literal, thanks! I like this solution because is compact, clear and doesn't need extra lines of complexity.

Comment: `std::format("({},{})", a, b);` [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4h9e9786d)

Answer (score 2):

You could just write

```
char a = '1';
char b = '2';

std::string s = std::string( "(" ) + a + "," + b + ")";
```

Or

```
char a = '1';
char b = '2';

string s;

for ( char c : { '(', a, ',', b, ')' } )
{
    s += c;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    char a = '1';
    char b = '2';

    std::string s = std::string( "(" ) + a + "," + b + ")";

    std::cout << "s = " << s << '\n';

    std::string t;

    for ( char c : { '(', a, ',', b, ')' } )
    {
        t += c;
    }

    std::cout << "t = " << t << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
s = (1,2)
t = (1,2)
```

Or you could use just a constructor like

```
std::string s( { '(', a, ',', b, ')' } );
```

or the method assign

```
std::string s;
s.assign( { '(', a, ',', b, ')' } );
```

or append

```
std::string s;
s.append( { '(', a, ',', b, ')' } );
```

Here is another demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    char a = '1';
    char b = '2';

    std::string s1( { '(', a, ',', b, ')' } );

    std::cout << "s1 = " << s1 << '\n';

    std::string s2;
    s2.assign( { '(', a, ',', b, ')' } );

    std::cout << "s2 = " << s2 << '\n';

    std::string s3( "The pair is " );
    s3.append( { '(', a, ',', b, ')' } );

    std::cout << "s3 = " << s3 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
s1 = (1,2)
s2 = (1,2)
s3 = The pair is (1,2)
```

Comment: Your `for` loop could be replaced with a single call to [`std::string::append()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) instead: `s.append({ '(', a, ',', b, ')' });`